# Can't bring the wifi interface up on Debian based os

Tags: network-interface

I was making a mess while trying to setup two working static ip addresses when i managed to turn down the wifi interface, and now I can't turn it up again, I've alredy tried:

- `ifup wlp19s0` output: `interface wlp19s0 already configured`
- `ifconfig wlp19s0 up` gives no output but nothing changes
- `ip link set dev wlp19s0 up` gives no output but nothing changes again
- `ifup -a` no output but nothing changes

`rfkill list` all shows that the device is not either soft or hard blocked, it was soft blocked before I removed the block

ls -a in /run/network gives:

```
ifstate ifstate.enp7s0 ifstate.lo ifstate.wlp19s0 .ifstate.lock ifup-wlp19s0.pid
```

.ifstate.lock is empty, somone suggested to try deleting it so I did, it just appeared again, I don't know when, not after ifup or ifconfig.

wlp19s0.pid contains a pid, ther isn't any process with that pid running

/run/network/ifstate looks like this:

```
enp7s0=enp7s0
wlp19s0=wlp19s0
lo=lo
```

I added wlps0=wlps0 by myself because it wasn't there, i also added wlps0 in /run/network/ifstate.wlp19s0 (it was empty before)

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp7s0
auto enp7s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto wlp19s0
iface wlp19s0 inet dhcp
```

I also tried:

`systemctl restart networking.service`, sometimes it ends in an istant without any error and nothing changes and sometimes takes several minutes and then fails

`systemctl status networking.service` and `journalctl -xe` gives this output:
Start operation timed out. Terminating

Rebooted several times during all the attempts.

Problem is definetly me making a mess with the network configuration since it has been working for years since now.

OS: `elementary os 5.1.5 Hera`

At the moment, I don't have enough reputation to comment or answer to comments.

Sorry if something is not indented/typos, I'm writing this from my phone

Edit: after making backups I completly deleted the entire disk and installed Windows 10 (didn't have a linux iso) and now it works, pretty sure it isn't the answer you were looking for but still...